# how to draw route using multiple waypoints swift4

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, direction, google-directions-api

i want to draw route between multiple points using start location and end location, i  am following some examples and this link to get json to get waypoints
https://directionsdebug.firebaseapp.com/?origin=place_id%3AChIJ59dGBGBwTDkRlQsbxkBkqNw&destination=place_id%3AChIJ0TGAdgh6TDkRTFcRvOIXIOY&mode=driving&waypoints=Kotri%2C%20Jamshoro%2C%20Sindh%2C%20Pakistan&alternatives=true

and this is my code i am not getting all the points using link please guide me how to this using start end and waypoints

```
func drawpath() {

        let url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=place_id%3AChIJ59dGBGBwTDkRlQsbxkBkqNw&destination=place_id%3AChIJ0TGAdgh6TDkRTFcRvOIXIOY&mode=driving&waypoints=Kotri%2C%20Jamshoro%2C%20Sindh%2C%20Pakistan&alternatives=true&key=AIzaSyCct09KdoyIc3VV5Bziw5Tk9MF0RhWXTNE"
        Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON { response in

            print(response.request as Any)  // original URL request
            print(response.response as Any) // HTTP URL response
            print(response.data as Any)     // server data
            print(response.result as Any)   // result of response serialization

            let json = try!  JSON(data: response.data!)
            let routes = json["routes"][0]["legs"][0]["steps"].arrayValue
            print("route is\(routes)")
            // print route using Polyline
            for route in routes
            {
                let routeOverviewPolyline = route["polyline"].dictionary
                let points = routeOverviewPolyline?["points"]?.stringValue
                print("ppoint\(String(describing: points))")
                print("routeOverviewPolyline\(String(describing: routeOverviewPolyline))")
                let path = GMSPath.init(fromEncodedPath: points!)
                let polyline = GMSPolyline.init(path: path)
                polyline.strokeWidth = 4
                polyline.strokeColor = UIColor.red
                polyline.map = self.mapview
            }


    }
```

Comment: its may help you  https://stackoverflow.com/a/42825924/5461400

Comment: no bro this example is a animation on route i dont want this , i  want to draw route using multiple waypoints

Answer (score 0):

Try this code may it help you (The route between source and destination points)

```
let origin = "\(37.778483),\(-122.513960)"
    let destination = "\(37.706753),\(-122.418677)"
    let url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=\(origin)&destination=\(destination)&mode=driving&key=[YOUR-API-KEY]"

    Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON { response in
        let json = JSON(data: response.data!)
        let routes = json["routes"].arrayValue

        for route in routes
        {
            let routeOverviewPolyline = route["overview_polyline"].dictionary
            let points = routeOverviewPolyline?["points"]?.stringValue
            let path = GMSPath.init(fromEncodedPath: points!)

            let polyline = GMSPolyline(path: path)
            polyline.strokeColor = .black
            polyline.strokeWidth = 10.0
            polyline.map = mapViewX

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

i found a mistake in determining the polyline to be created, you should use the "overview_polyline" object from the response

[image]

so I made a slight change of the code you have made into:

```
func drawpath() {

        let url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=place_id%3AChIJ59dGBGBwTDkRlQsbxkBkqNw&destination=place_id%3AChIJ0TGAdgh6TDkRTFcRvOIXIOY&mode=driving&waypoints=Kotri%2C%20Jamshoro%2C%20Sindh%2C%20Pakistan&alternatives=true&key=AIzaSyCct09KdoyIc3VV5Bziw5Tk9MF0RhWXTNE"
        Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON { response in

            print(response.request as Any)  // original URL request
            print(response.response as Any) // HTTP URL response
            print(response.data as Any)     // server data
            print(response.result as Any)   // result of response serialization

            let json = try!  JSON(data: response.data!)
            let routes = json["routes"][0]["overview_polyline"]["points"].stringValue

            let path = GMSPath.init(fromEncodedPath: routes)
            let polyline = GMSPolyline.init(path: path)
            polyline.strokeWidth = 4
            polyline.strokeColor = UIColor.red
            polyline.map = self.mapview
    }
```

output I get:

[image]

hopefully can help.