# Smoothly Animate in GMS poly line using google direction api from steps point poly line in iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to move smoothly animated polyline with using google direction api. From API Response, I am getting each polyline points from steps of legs Array. As Written code below , output of animation polyline is not moving continously as I want, So give any idea for regular or continuous movement of poly line on drawn route.

```
var gmsPath = GMSMutablePath()
var path = GMSPath()
var polyline = GMSPolyline()
var animationPath = GMSMutablePath()
var animationPolyline = GMSPolyline()

func polyline(){

self.createPolyline(arrStep: arrPath, complitionBlock: { (success) in
        if success{
                    print("Success")
                    self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.3, target: self, selector: #selector(self.animatePath), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
                   }else{
                        print("Did not success")
                    }
                })
 }

////Create Polyline On MAP

func createPolyline(arrStep:[String],complitionBlock : @escaping (Bool)->Void){

    for points in arrStep{

        self.gmsPath.appendPath(path: GMSMutablePath(fromEncodedPath: points))
        self.polyline.path = gmsPath
        self.polyline.strokeColor = UIColor.blue
        self.polyline.strokeWidth = 4.0
        self.polyline.map = self.gmsMapView
    }
    complitionBlock(true)
}
////Animate Path In Polyline

@objc func animatePath() {

    if (self.i < self.gmsPath.count()){
        self.animationPath.add(self.gmsPath.coordinate(at: UInt(self.i)))
        self.animationPolyline.path = self.animationPath
        self.animationPolyline.strokeColor = UIColor.purple
        self.animationPolyline.strokeWidth = 4
        self.animationPolyline.map = self.gmsMapView
        self.i += 1
    }else{
        self.i = 0
        self.animationPath = GMSMutablePath()
        self.animationPolyline.map = nil
    }

}
```

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/42833144/5523205

Comment: m also try this code. I want to create polyline from encoded points from steps which is in legs array Response in direction api.Not from overview polyline points.thanks